# Match closest (distance) cell to current

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row of numbers and blank cells and need to find the closest column with a blank in the row  of the current formula. Is there some way to do this? Match doesn't work because it finds the first or last, and I need the closest one.
For example row 1 is `{1,54,"",2,869,"",584,47,15,"",...}` and in row 2 I want the number of the closest (smaller) blank column in row 1. So in cell G2 I want it to find column F or 6.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file or screenshot about your requirement?

Comment: I'm thinking you could split your formula into two components, so in your example if you are starting at G2, then have a formula look for the Last blank from A1 to G1 and another formula to look for the first blank from G1 to the end of your data. then compare those two numbers and return a result based on that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

For a reverse lookup, use the [XMATCH function](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/09/09/excel-xmatch-function-formula-examples/)

=XMATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("$A$1:"&CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),-1,0)))),0,-1)